# Textfield text match array from text file

Tags: cocoa-touch, textfield

This is my code to get each word from a text file into a NSArray but it simply doesn't work when I try to match one of the words in the array to my textfield.

```
-(NSString*) replaceBadWords:(NSString*)userText {

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"badwords" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"lines: %@", lines);

for(NSString* s in lines){
    userText =[userText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:s withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,[userText length])];
}

return userText;
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSNotification *)notif {
    NSLog(@"textfielddidchange");
    NSString *tmp = [self replaceBadWords:Name.text];
    NSLog(@"tmp: %@", tmp);
    if(![tmp isEqualToString:Name.text])
        Name.text = tmp;
}
```

This code fires when the textfield text changes whenever the user types a new word/letter. Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

In the end, I just want to see if the textfield text matches a word that was in the text file, and if it is, then make the textfield.text, nil. But this code does not do that, I just need to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

I think you need :

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

because:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange
```

fires over and over after first first letter written.

Comment: I don't think so because this method has to fire after every letter typed or deleted to check if its a bad word.

Comment: Nope, I did,: - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)notif and I did this in the VDL... [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:) name:@"textFieldDidBeginEditingNotification" object:Name]; 
Why isn't that working?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if(![tmp isEqualToString:Name.text])
```

means that they should not be the same. Is that what u want?

Comment: Well if I take out the !, it causes the nslog to continuously fire so I don't think I want it to do that. In the end, I just want to see if the textfield text matches a word that was in the text file, and if it is, then make the textfield.text, nil.